# Declare variable as global inside block __name__ == "__main__"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Inside the block

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

do I need to declare a variable as global in order to set its value?
Or... is this block not a function and hence I don't need to do this?

I guess the latter is true but I want to double-check and make sure I understand this better.

Comment: It is not a function. Please read [mcve] for creating a more clear question.

Comment: There's nothing special about `if __name__ == "__main__":`, it is the same `if` construct as `if True:` with respect to scope. It is **definitely not a function**

Comment: `if` block does not have its own context.  Does not matter what it's used for.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to declare the variable, `global` keyword only makes sense in a function.

Comment: It's declared in the global scope, outside of all function bodies.

Answer (score 3):

```
if __name__ == "__main__"
```

This if statement does not have its own context, therefore variables can be modified without the need for the global keyword.